# Look up pulseaudio sink-input index by property

Tags: pulseaudio

The output of both `pactl list sink-inputs` and `pacmd list-sink-inputs` contains a Properties section:

```
Properties:
    media.name = "ALSA Playback"
    application.name = "ALSA plug-in [snapclient]"
    native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
    native-protocol.version = "29"
    application.process.id = "6393"
    application.process.user = "root"
    application.process.host = "xxxxxx"
    application.process.binary = "snapclient"
    application.language = "C"
    application.process.machine_id = "8dadf95c2f504864bc0f8b3ab149cbe0"
    application.process.session_id = "c4"
    module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-application-name:ALSA plug-in [snapclient]"
```

I am wondering if there is a way to directly look up the index of a sink-input by either the `application.process.id` or `application.process.binary`, without resorting to parsing the many lines of output of the aforementioned commands or writing a separate C program.

Comment: This would be a great question on [unix.se] but it's not about programming. You just want to know how to resolve a name to an ID in pulse audio.

Answer (score 5):

Some commands also accept the unique name instead of the id, but the ones you are trying to use seem to not be able to do so.. probably because the name is not unique and there could be mulitple matches. You need to parse it yourself. This is what I came up with:

```sh
pacmd list-sink-inputs |
tr '\n' '\r' |
perl -pe 's/.*? *index: ([0-9]+).+?application\.name = "([^\r]+)"\r.+?(?=index:|$)/\2:\1\r/g' |
tr '\r' '\n'
```

`perl -pe` is like `sed`, just better. This basically matches `[anything] [index]: [id] [anything] [application.name] = [name] [anything]` and formats the output to something like

```sh
"speech-dispatcher":166
"SoX":407
"Clementine":413
```

Which you then can grep or sed.

Maybe you want to adjust `application\.name` to something more suitable to you.

Comment: This is very useful for what I'm trying to do now, thanks!

Comment: ... or awk. A slightly modified example: `pacmd list-source-outputs | tr '\n' '\r' | perl -pe 's/ *index: ([0-9]+).+?media\.name = "([^\r]+)"\r.+?(?=index:|$)/\2:\1\r/g' | tr '\r' '\n' | awk -F ":" '/AudioCallbackDriver/ {print $2}'`

Comment: application.name isn't always set, but application.process.binary seems to be: `pacmd list-sink-inputs | tr '\n' '\r' | perl -pe 's/ *index: ([0-9]+).+?application\.process\.binary = "([^\r]+)"\r.+?(?=index:|$)/\2:\1\r/g' | tr '\r' '\n'`

Comment: my first sink is `properties: media.name = "LADSPA Stream" media.role = "filter" module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-media-role:filter"` so this doesn't work for me

Comment: @br4nnigan So your sink does not have an `application.name` property? What about `application.process.binary`, as hinted by Allanrbo above? You need to specify some usable property at least or your respective non-matching sinks will simply be ignored.

Comment: application.process.binary is also not always set for things like `pactl load-module module-echo-cancel`, this is now getting sink input indexes mixed up :(

Answer (score 2):

Although it does parse the output and doesn't yet do any matching for the id you may be looking for, this method will provide a way, with some modifications, to get that information by sink id:

```
pactl list sink-inputs | while read -r line ; do

  #echo "Processing ${line}"
  echo $line | grep -oP 'Sink Input #\K[^$]'
  echo $line | grep -oP 'application.process.id = "\K[^"]+'
  echo $line | grep -oP 'application.process.binary = "\K[^"]+'

done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short solution to OP's question:

```
$ cat pulse-get-sink-input-for-pid
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then >&2 echo Need PID; exit 1; fi
export pid=$1
pactl list sink-inputs | perl -nle '/Sink Input #(\d+)/ and $si = $1; /application.process.id.*?(\d+)/ and ($1 == $ENV{pid}) and print "$si"'
```

Answer (score 0):

The very long, easy to understand, maintainable way to do it (using **application.process.binary**)

*Result*

```
ffmpeg | 3
firefox-esr | 24
firefox-esr | 58
vlc | 43
```

*Bash script*

```
str="$(pacmd list-sink-inputs)"

list1=$(printf '%s' "$str" | grep 'index: ')
list2=$(printf '%s' "$str" | grep 'application.process.binary = "')

arr1=()
arr2=()

while read line; do
    arr1+=("${line:7}")
done <<< "$list1"

while read line; do
    arr2+=("${line:30:-1}")
done <<< "$list2"

for index in ${!arr1[@]}; do
    s1="${arr1[index]}"
    s2="${arr2[index]}"

    echo "$s2 | $s1"
done
```

*Another way to do it* (a bit more obscure)

```
str="$(pacmd list-sink-inputs)"

arr1=($(printf '%s' "$str" | grep 'index: ' | rev | cut -d' ' -f 1 | rev))
arr2=($(printf '%s' "$str" | grep 'application.process.binary' | cut -d'"' -f 2))

for index in ${!arr1[@]}; do
    s1="${arr1[index]}"
    s2="${arr2[index]}"

    echo "$s2 | $s1"
done
```

And finally, the shortest solution I found :

```
str="$(pacmd list-sink-inputs)"

paste -d\| \
<(printf '%s' "$str" | grep 'application.process.binary' | cut -d'"' -f 2) \
<(printf '%s' "$str" | grep 'index: ' | rev | cut -d' ' -f 1 | rev)
```

Comment: Sadly all of these fail and get the indexes mixed up if there are any sink inputs that don't have an application.process.binary such as `pactl load-module module-echo-cancel` :(

Comment: @Baa Interesting, I did not consider this case!